# Need to create a loop until last row, but only for certain ranges

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub asd()

Sheets("Price calculator other regions").Range("E6").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")

Sheets("Price calculator other regions").Range("E25").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5")

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D5").Value = Sheets("Price calculator other regions").Range("E32")

End Sub
```

I need the values B5, C5 and D5 to move one row below (B6, C6, D6 and so on) until the last row, but the values on "Price calculator other regions" need to remain fixed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kudos for going for the value transfer instead of copy/pasting!**

To complete your loop, you just need to sub your relevant row numbers with a counter variable (variable `i`). To implement, find the last row (determined by `Sheet 1 Column B`), then, loop through your rows.

The loop is currently set to start at the 2nd row on `Sheet 1`. If you need to start on the 5th row, change the loop to `For i = 5 to LR`

---

```
Sub asd_v2()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ps As Worksheet: Set ps = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Price calculator other regions")

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LR
    ps.Range("E6").Value = ws.Range("B" & i).Value
    ps.Range("E25").Value = ws.Range("C" & i).Value
    ws.Range("D" & i).Value = ps.Range("E32").Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim r as range
set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
do  'start loop
with Sheets("Price calculator other regions")

.Range("E6").Value = r

.Range("E25").Value = r.offset(0,1)

r.offset(0,2) = .Range("E32")
set r = r.offset(1,0)
loop until r.row > r.parent.usedrange.rows.count

end with
```